# How can I increase the number of triggers executed simultaneously in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, loading

I have a table with foreign key constraints to which many clients load data simultaneously. I noticed that when there are a few clients adding new data then everything works fine, however, for more than about 10 clients everything slows down significantly! Do you have any idea why it is happening? PostgreSQL says that: *"each new row requires an entry in the server's list of pending trigger events (since it is the firing of a trigger that checks the row's foreign key constraint). Loading many millions of rows can cause the trigger event queue to overflow available memory, leading to intolerable swapping or even outright failure of the command."* I cannot remove triggers in my case. Do you know how to increase the size of the list of pending trigger events? I did not observer any swapping to disk. Moreover, I check the locks using this query:

```
select locktype, relname, pid, mode from pg_locks,pg_class where pg_locks.relation=pg_class.oid;
```

and the locks don't show anything special.